# Compare two cells for different values in Excel

Tags: excel, comparison, formula

I may of got the Title slightly wrong but basically,

I have two cells.

One containing either: "Positive: 1" or "Negative: 0", or "Neutral"
and
One containing either: "Positive" or "Negative", or "Neutral"

I need to compare these two and find out whether they match in another and output 1 if they do 0 if they don't.

I have tried various if and match statements but am struggling and wondering if someone here may be really good at Excel formulas could help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should work (if A1 is your first cell, and B1 is your second):

```
=IF(LEFT(A1, 3) = LEFT(B1, 3), 1, 0)
```

The "3" is the number of characters to read into the string in the selected cell.

Comment: This doesn't work for 'Neutral' as that is 7 characters long and 'Negative' and 'Positive' are 8

Comment: That doesn't matter - the only unique part is the first 2 chars.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
=IF(ISERR(SEARCH(A1,B1)),0,1)
```